# Javafx return user specific values after log in

Tags: mysql, javafx

I am making gym log in java fx with option to sing/login. 
When the user logs into application for the first time new table in database is created with doubles (eg, healthPoints, userWeight etc), I made one user USER with values 10,10
And another user USER2 with 5,5,
After I log in with USER I would like to return this user  values from its table in its profile page (doubles display in the labels) 
And if I log in with USER2 I want to return its specific details in profile page

I will provide my code once I get access to my computer

Comment: Are you sure about that 1 table per user decision? Usually I'd create a table for the users and a table for the values that contains a foreign key refering to the user table...

Comment: You plan to create a separate table for each user? Like fabian mentioned, that is a very odd design decision and will very likely cause some big problems in the future...

Comment: I will take your advice guys

Comment: What kind of complications?

Comment: I did what fabian sugested,
How do i return  the values of User1 from the child table(main table is users and refered table is userParms), i didn't work much with tables with foreign keys before in Java